# How to filter csv file by date column using awk whenever date format constraint does not match date format column?

Tags: bash, csv, date, awk

I need to filter a csv file whom 25th column has the following date format "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss", in order to only display the entire lines containing today's date, and put them in a separate file (hope that's clear).

I went over a few topics and tried to adapt solutions to my script but I can't make it work.

So right now, I am back to the following :

> today= date '+%Y-%m-%d'
>
> awk -F ";" '{ if ($25 == '$today') print }'
> input.csv > today.csv'

I am aware that I am asking something stupid like "if YYYY-MM-DD == YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss, then do something"

My question is, is there a way to put a wildcard somewhere in my today's variable, or should I set two different variables like :

> today_start = date '+%Y-%m-%d' 00:00:00
>
> today_end = date '+%Y-%m-%d' 23:59:59

and then create a condition stating that if column value is between today_start and _today_end, something needs to be done.

Also, I need to keep the format of date column as it is (YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss).

Thanks a lot in advance, hope someone can help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex to match the start of your field, i.e. match the first 10 characters (YYYY-MM-DD) of the field.

```
today=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')
awk -v regex="^$today" -F';' '$25 ~ regex' input.csv > today.csv
```

This passes the value of the `$today` variable with `-v` to `awk` and prepends a `^` to match the start of the field.